# how to load html file in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

DIV tag is not rendering HTML file .
Whats the problem in coding mentioned below.Help

**CSS**:

```
#-ImageSlider
{   
    width:50%;
    height:75%;
    margin-left:3%;
    margin-top:5%;
    display:inline-block;
    left: 100 px;
    border:thick solid black;

}
```

**JS**:

```
  <script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
       $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#-ImageSlider").load("\Cover Slider\index.html");
    });
      </script>
```

P.S - CoverSlider is another folder which contains another project with html file index.html. It resides in working directory

Comment: `Cover Slider` does it has a space in it?

Comment: Please make a fiddle: jsfiddle.net

Comment: did you include the jQuery..?

Comment: yes it does have space

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="../ImageSlider2/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
I have included this Jquery

Comment: @RahulDesai I dnt know anything about fiddle !! what it will do ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MgRhT/ @RahulDesai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if you have spaces in it and `\` these slashes, try replacing with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#-ImageSlider").load("/CoverSlider/index.html");
});       //-----------------^-----^-----^--------------see this
```

As your comments:

*Same folder `d:/project/CoverSlider` and all my files are in D:/project/*

`d:/project/CoverSlider` this is not the way to do a ajax request. You have to setup a local server environment on your system. So if you do that then you can only access your page because `.load()` is an another ajax feature of ajax  and ajax requests can only be done on server not in the file system.

Comment: Nada ,  no change.
Do i need to run my html and this jquery using a server or it should work without it.

Comment: do you have your folder at the same level where your file is.

Comment: try with removing `/` the first one.

Comment: Same folder d:/project/CoverSlider
and  all my files are in D:/project/

Comment: so you are not woking on `localhost` or i would say `local server environment`, if this is the case then your `.load()` jQuery method won't work because this is an `ajax` feature and ajax requests can only done on server not in ths file system.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('Folder/test.html')
     .success(function(data) {
         $("#-ImageSlider").html(data);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
       $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#ImageSlider').load("/Cover Slider/index.html");
    });
      </script>
```

**[demo1](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

please `remove (-)` in this `"#-ImageSlider"`

please `write` `"#ImageSlider"`

in `id` `(-)` is `not required.`